# cassandra 2.1 thread cpu user time 100

Tags: java, cassandra

I use several processes to write cassandra through tcp. It's fine at first. After memory reach 50%, my processes have got a lot of timeout. At this time the cpu user time of one cassandra thread reach 100% for a very long time, and  the system.log is as follow:

```
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,996 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.AVE_WK                         1906,2098
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,997 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.RRA                                  0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,997 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.schema_triggers                    0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,997 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.local                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,997 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.peers                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,997 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.batchlog                           0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,998 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.NodeIdInfo                         0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,998 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.compactions_in_progress                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,998 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.schema_usertypes                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,998 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.schema_keyspaces                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,998 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.compaction_history                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,998 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.paxos                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,999 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.schema_columns                     0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,999 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.schema_columnfamilies                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,999 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.IndexInfo                          0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,999 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.range_xfers                        0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:43,999 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.peer_events                        0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:44,000 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.hints                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:44,000 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.sstable_activity                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:44,000 StatusLogger.java:115 - system_traces.sessions                    0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:01:44,000 StatusLogger.java:115 - system_traces.events                      0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:06,068 GCInspector.java:116 - GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 21284 ms for 1 collections, 4226524688 used; max is 4242538496
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:06,069 StatusLogger.java:51 - Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,897 StatusLogger.java:66 - CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,898 StatusLogger.java:66 - ReadStage                         0         0            106         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,898 StatusLogger.java:66 - RequestResponseStage              0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,899 StatusLogger.java:66 - ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,899 StatusLogger.java:66 - MutationStage                    32        92          20620         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,900 StatusLogger.java:66 - GossipStage                       0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,900 StatusLogger.java:66 - AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,901 StatusLogger.java:66 - MigrationStage                    0         0              8         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,901 StatusLogger.java:66 - MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,902 StatusLogger.java:66 - MemtableFlushWriter               2         8             23         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,902 StatusLogger.java:66 - PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              1         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,903 StatusLogger.java:66 - MemtablePostFlush                 1        46             69         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,903 StatusLogger.java:66 - commitlog_archiver                0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,904 StatusLogger.java:66 - InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,904 StatusLogger.java:66 - HintedHandoff                     0         0              0         0                 0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,905 StatusLogger.java:75 - CompactionManager                 0         0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,905 StatusLogger.java:87 - MessagingService                n/a       0/0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,905 StatusLogger.java:97 - Cache Type                     Size                 Capacity               KeysToSave
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,905 StatusLogger.java:99 - KeyCache                       2208                104857600                      all
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,905 StatusLogger.java:105 - RowCache                          0                        0                      all
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,906 StatusLogger.java:112 - ColumnFamily                Memtable ops,data
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,906 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.DS                                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,906 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.CDP                       2226732,476355
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,906 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.AVE_MO                         3040,3722
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,906 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.PDP                        923845,604642
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,906 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.AVE_HR                   943064,83811099
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,907 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.AVE_YR                           120,164
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,907 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.AVE_WK                         3040,3722
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,907 StatusLogger.java:115 - RRD2.RRA                                  0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,916 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.schema_triggers                    0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,916 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.local                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,916 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.peers                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:21,936 StatusLogger.java:115 - system.batchlog                           0,0
WARN  [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] 2014-05-09 15:08:56,334 AbstractCommitLogService.java:105 - Out of 11 commit log syncs over the past 321s with average duration of 26478.00ms, 7 have exceeded the configured commit interval by an average of 31464.57ms
```

Any one knows what's going on?

Comment: `WARN  [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] 2014-05-09 15:08:56,334 AbstractCommitLogService.java:105 - Out of 11 commit log syncs over the past 321s with average duration of 26478.00ms, 7 have exceeded the configured commit interval by an average of 31464.57ms`. Dont know what cassandra is but exceeding the configured commit interval by ***32s*** seems fishy to me.

Comment: This is not an on-topic programming question as defined in the [help/on-topic], it's about NoSQL database administration, and thus belongs on [dba.se].

Comment: @Cupcake: I'm glad it was here, the other stack sites don't always get indexed as well.

Answer (score 1):

This line here indicates that you are overloading the node such that it is running our of java heap space:

```
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-05-09 15:02:06,068 GCInspector.java:116 - GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 21284 ms for 1 collections, 4226524688 used; max is 4242538496
```

You probably need to tune back some of the caches or memtables or something.  If you take a heap dump you could figure out what is using all the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just a followup as to why you are seeing the StatusLogger entries.  Status logger dumps out some key metrics during specific times of 'stress' on Cassandra.  As Zanson pointed out you are specifically seeing this due to garbage collection runs.

By default, there is a config entry called `gc_log_threshold_in_ms` which defaults to 200ms(adjustable in the config), any garbage collection >200ms will log the status logger entries you are seeing.

Additionally, there is another config entry called `gc_warn_threshhold_in_ms` which will log those entries at the `WARN` log level instead of `INFO` if the garbage collection runs are >1000ms (by default, also adjustable).